# Creating Context Menu Item For Multiple Files

Tags: context-menu

I created a context menu item with this line:

"C:\Documents and Settings\mmurphy\My Documents\My Tools\WinMerge-2.12.0-exe\WinMergeU.exe" /s "%1" "%2"

I selected two files and expected when I clicked on the menu item it would open the executable and pass those two files in as arguments. What happened was it opened two separate instances of the application and passed only one of the arguments to each instance of the app.

How would I do this so that I can select two files, right click on them and execute my app so that the two files I have selected get passed in as arguments for only one instance of the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I soved my problem... sorta...I'm using a different compare program... instead of using WinMerge (free) my company bought us copies of UltraCompare (not free) ... it has a context menu item that does exactly what I want.